# ¿Como soluciono un Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String?

Tags: java

Mi codigo es este:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*; 






/*
 *- Interfaz Nomina -
 *  Programa que muestra una interfaz para consultar nominas.

 */

/**
 *
 * @author Marily Huerta/Frida Fuentes.
 * @since 03/diciembre/2018
 */
public class InterfazNominaSueldo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
      JLabel T1,T2,T3;
      JLabel Empleado,HorasTrabajadas,RN,Sue,PHEX,SueB,Dedu,DIMSS,DISPT,SueN;
      JButton BCerrar,BLimpiar,BSueldoN;
      JTextField NomEmp,HT,S,PEXT,SB,DEDU,DEDUIMSS,DEDUISPT,SN;

      double SUELDONETO,HRST,SUELDO,PAGOEXT,SUEB,DEDUC,DEDIMSS,DEDISPT,SUEN;
    private double PAGOEXTRA;
      public InterfazNominaSueldo(){
         setLayout(null);

            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
          T1=new JLabel("   C.B.T.I.S  No. 189");
             T1.setBounds(120,10,120,50);    
             add(T1);
          T2= new JLabel("  CALCULAR NOMINA EMPLEADOS");
          T2.setBounds(100,30,300,50);    
             add(T2);

          T3= new JLabel("     INTRODUCIR DATOS");
          T3.setBounds(90,50,500,50);    
             add(T3);


        Empleado=new JLabel("  Empleado");
        Empleado.setBounds(30,90,700,50);    
             add(Empleado);


        HorasTrabajadas= new JLabel(" Horas Trabajadas ");
        HorasTrabajadas.setBounds(30,120,900,50);    
             add(HorasTrabajadas);

        RN=new JLabel("Recibo Nomina");  
        RN.setBounds(140, 215, 900, 50);
           add(RN);  
        Sue=new JLabel(" Sueldo");     
        Sue.setBounds(90, 255, 900, 50);
        add(Sue);
        PHEX= new JLabel("Pago Horas Extra");
        PHEX.setBounds(30, 280, 900, 50);
        add(PHEX);
        SueB=new JLabel("Sueldo Bruto");
        SueB.setBounds(55,300,900,50);
        add(SueB);
        Dedu=new JLabel("Deducciones");
        Dedu.setBounds(50,320,900,50);
        add(Dedu);
        DIMSS=new JLabel("IMSS");
        DIMSS.setBounds(97,340,900,50);
        add(DIMSS);
        DISPT=new JLabel("ISPT");
        DISPT.setBounds(98,360,900,50);
        add(DISPT);
        SueN=new JLabel("Sueldo Neto");
        SueN.setBounds(58,395,900,50);
        add(SueN);

        BCerrar=new JButton(" CERRAR");
        BCerrar.setBounds(10,200 ,90 ,20 );
        add(BCerrar);
        BCerrar.addActionListener(this);


    BLimpiar=new JButton(" LIMPIAR ");
        BLimpiar.setBounds(120,200 ,100 ,20 );
        add(BLimpiar);
        BLimpiar.addActionListener(this);


    BSueldoN=new JButton(" SUELDO ");
        BSueldoN.setBounds(250,200 ,100 ,20 );
        add(BSueldoN);
        BSueldoN.addActionListener(this);    

     NomEmp=new JTextField();   
      NomEmp.setBounds(160,110,100,20);
            add(NomEmp);
HT=new JTextField();   
      HT.setBounds(160,135,90,20);
            add(HT);


 S=new JTextField();
    S.setBounds(150,268 ,100 ,20 );
        add(S);

 PEXT=new JTextField();
 PEXT.setBounds(150,290,100,20);
        add(PEXT);
 SB=new JTextField();
 SB.setBounds(150,312,100,20);
       add(SB);
 DEDU=new JTextField();
 DEDU.setBounds(150,335,100,20);
       add(DEDU);

 DEDUIMSS=new JTextField();
 DEDUIMSS.setBounds(150,358,100,20);
       add(DEDUIMSS);

  DEDUISPT=new JTextField();
 DEDUISPT.setBounds(150,380,100,20);
       add(DEDUISPT);  
   SN=new JTextField();
 SN.setBounds(150,410,100,20);
       add(SN);  
      } 





    public static void main(String[] args) {
         InterfazNominaSueldo Ventana=new InterfazNominaSueldo();
          Ventana.setBounds(0,0,400,500);
          Ventana.setVisible(true);
          Ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }



public void actionPerformed(Action EventEvento){
        if (Evento.getSource() == BCerrar){
           System.exit(0);
       }

       if (Evento.getSource() == BLimpiar){
           NomEmp.setText("");
           HT.setText("");
           S.setText("");
           PEXT.setText("");
           SB.setText("");
           DEDU.setText("");
           DEDUIMSS.setText("");
           SN.setText("");
       }

       if (Evento.getSource() == BSueldoN){

    }
    }
      @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Evento) {
        if (Evento.getSource() == BCerrar){
           System.exit(0);
       }

       if (Evento.getSource() == BLimpiar){
           NomEmp.setText("");
           HT.setText("");
           S.setText("");
           PEXT.setText("");
           SB.setText("");
           DEDU.setText("");
           DEDUIMSS.setText("");
           SN.setText("");
       }

       if (Evento.getSource() == BSueldoN){
    HRST=Float.parseFloat(HT.getText());
    PAGOEXTRA=Float.parseFloat(PEXT.getText()); 
    final float SUEHRS=70;
    final float SUEHX=140;
    double HRSEXT;

    if(HRST>40)
    {

        HRSEXT=HRST-40;
        PAGOEXTRA= HRSEXT*SUEHX;
        HRST=40;
    }
    SUELDO=(HRST*SUEHRS);
    SUEB=SUELDO+PAGOEXT;
    DEDIMSS=(float) (SUEB*0.03);
    DEDISPT=(float) (SUEB*0.02);
       DEDUC=DEDIMSS+DEDISPT;
       SUEN=SUEB-DEDIMSS-DEDISPT;


       S.setText(String.valueOf(SUELDO));
       SB.setText(String.valueOf(SUEB));
       DEDU.setText(String.valueOf(DEDUC));
       DEDUIMSS.setText(String.valueOf(DEDIMSS));
       DEDUISPT.setText(String.valueOf(DEDISPT));
       SN.setText(String.valueOf(SUEN)); 




    }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema se genera aquí:

```
HRST=Float.parseFloat(HT.getText());
PAGOEXTRA=Float.parseFloat(PEXT.getText());
```

recuerda que para realizar la conversión debes realizarlo a partir de valores numéricos, si introduces un valor no numerico como una letra, un espacio o un cadena vacía en `HT` y `PEXT` obtendras el error:

> NumberFormatException: empty String?

en este caso se esta indicando que los `JTextField` en realidad no tienen valor especificado.

Para esto puedes realizar una validación usando el método:

```
public float validaFloat(String number){
    float result = 0; //Valor default.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Float.parseFloat(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //*No es numerico!
    }
    return result;
}
```

y lo usarías de esta forma:

```
//HRST=Float.parseFloat(HT.getText());
  HRST=validaFloat(HT.getText());
//PAGOEXTRA=Float.parseFloat(PEXT.getText()); 
  PAGOEXTRA=validaFloat(PEXT.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema efectivamente resulta de intentar parsear las líneas:

```
HRST=Float.parseFloat(HT.getText());
PAGOEXTRA=Float.parseFloat(PEXT.getText());
```

Para este tipo de interfaz personalmente aplico una restricción al JTextField para forzar el uso de números y un punto, de esta forma:

```
    HT.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            char caracter = evt.getKeyChar();
            //Verificar si ya existe un punto
            if (jPrecio.getText().contains(".") && (caracter == '.')) {
                evt.consume();
            }
            // Verificar si la tecla pulsada no es un digito
            if (((caracter < '0')
                    || (caracter > '9'))
                    && (caracter != '.')
                    && (caracter != '\b' /*corresponde a BACK_SPACE*/)) {
                evt.consume();  // ignorar el evento de teclado
            }
        }
    });
```

Y, justo reconocido el evento, verificar la existencia del dato o solicitarlo así:

```
  if (Evento.getSource() == BSueldoN){
    if (HT.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Ingrese las horas trabajadas",
                "Información faltante",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        return;
    } else {
        HRST = Float.parseFloat(HT.getText());
    }
....
```

Confirmado el dato se procede a parsear de forma segura. De esta forma no se detiene la aplicación y tampoco se podría continuar con los cálculos sin la información necesaria.

P.D. Se tendría que implementar también para el JTextField "PEXT"

Saludos