# ¿Como arreglo el error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String? ,es de java,me gustaría que me guíen

Tags: java, java-swing

Me podrían ayudar a resolver este problema en java, este es mi código, creo que el error esta en el parseo pero no se como hacerlo, me gustaría que me ayudaran, muchas gracias, se que no esta el código completo, pero se que el error esta en el parseo

```
    double yardas, millas, kilometros, centimetros, pulgadas, resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado4;
    
    
    centimetros = Double.parseDouble(txtCentimetros.getText());
    yardas = Double.parseDouble(txtYardas.getText());
    pulgadas = Double.parseDouble(txtPulgadas.getText());
    kilometros = Double.parseDouble(txtKilometros.getText());
    millas = Double.parseDouble(txtMillas.getText());
    System.out.println("hi");

    if (centimetros !=0 && yardas == 0 && pulgadas == 0 && kilometros == 0 && millas == 0){
        System.out.println("");
        resultado1 = centimetros/91.44;
        resultado2 = centimetros/2.54;
        resultado3 = centimetros/1000000;
        resultado4 = centimetros/160934.4;
       
        txtYardas.setText(""+resultado1);
        txtPulgadas.setText(""+resultado2);
        txtKilometros.setText(""+resultado3);
        txtMillas.setText(""+resultado4);
    }
    if (yardas !=0 && centimetros == 0 && pulgadas == 0 && kilometros == 0 && millas == 0){
        System.out.println("");
        resultado1 = yardas*91.44;
        resultado2 = yardas*36;
        resultado3 = yardas/1000000;
        resultado4 = yardas/160934.4;

        txtCentimetros.setText(""+resultado1);
        txtPulgadas.setText(""+resultado2);
        txtKilometros.setText(""+resultado3);
        txtMillas.setText(""+resultado4);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como soluciono un Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219906/como-soluciono-un-exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-numberformat)

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que estas parseando fuera de los condicionales, es decir a yardas, si parseas yardas pero nunca recibes valor entonces no puede parsear un valor vacio, lo que debes hacer es meter cada parseo dentro de cada codnicional, ejemplo:

```
if (centimetros !=0 && yardas == 0 && pulgadas == 0 && kilometros == 0 && millas == 0){
    centimetros = Double.parseDouble(txtCentimetros.getText());
    System.out.println("");
    resultado1 = centimetros/91.44;
    resultado2 = centimetros/2.54;
    resultado3 = centimetros/1000000;
    resultado4 = centimetros/160934.4;
   
    txtYardas.setText(""+resultado1);
    txtPulgadas.setText(""+resultado2);
    txtKilometros.setText(""+resultado3);
    txtMillas.setText(""+resultado4);
}
```

asi con cada uno de las conversiones, porque en el primer if solo verifica que ingreses valor en cm, el segundo en yardas y asi con todos

Comment: No me sirve bro, sigue saliendo el mismo error